# best way to delete unmatched records from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with productId, color, size and other fields. I created following array from post values. I update the table rows with matching fields product_id, color_id, size_id. But I need to delete unmatched other 2 rows. I tried below query.

```
DELETE FROM fc_product_quantities WHERE product_id=18 AND color_id NOT IN (9,1) AND size_id NOT IN (23,24)
```

But it's not working as I expected and no records has been deleted. Is there any other way to delete unmatched records using mysql and php.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 18
            [list] => 1
            [color] => 9
            [size] => 23
            [qty] => 10
            [price] => 522.22
            [offerprice] => 250.00
            [default] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 18
            [list] => 1
            [color] => 1
            [size] => 24
            [qty] => 25
            [price] => 145.22
            [offerprice] => 222.22
            [default] => 0
        )
)
```

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fc_product_quantities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qty_price` float(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `offer_price` float(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sold` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `fc_product_quantities` (`id`, `product_id`, `color_id`, `size_id`, `quantity`, `qty_price`, `offer_price`, `default`, `sold`) VALUES
(1, 18, 9, 23, 10, 522.22, 250.00, 1, 0),
(2, 18, 9, 22, 25, 245.55, 354.22, 0, 0),
(3, 18, 1, 22, 74, 444.44, 777.77, 0, 0),
(4, 18, 1, 24, 25, 145.22, 222.22, 0, 0);
```

PHP code

```
$totalSizesArr = array();
$totalColorsArr = array();
foreach ($quantities as $xKey => $xValue) {
    $pid = $xValue['pid'];
    $colorId = $xValue['color'];
    $sizeId = $xValue['size'];
    $qty = $xValue['qty'];
    $qPrice = $xValue['price'];
    $qOfferPrice = $xValue['offerprice'];
    $qDefault = $xValue['default'];

    $qtyDetails = $this->product_model->get_product_quantity($product_id,$colorId,$sizeId);
    if($qtyDetails->num_rows > 0) {
        $updateCondition = array(
            'product_id'=>$product_id,
            'color_id'=>$colorId,
            'size_id'=>$sizeId
            );
        $updateValues = array(
            'quantity'=>$qty,
            'qty_price'=>$qPrice,
            'offer_price'=>$qOfferPrice,
            'default'=>$qDefault
        );
        $this->product_model->update_details(PRODUCT_QUANTITIES,$updateValues,$updateCondition);
        echo $this->db->last_query();
        echo '</br>';
    } else {
        $uCondition = array();
        $uDatarr = array('product_id'=>$product_id,'color_id'=>$colorId,'size_id'=>$sizeId,'quantity'=>$qty,'qty_price'=>$qPrice,'offer_price'=>$qOfferPrice,'default'=>$qDefault);
        $this->product_model->commonInsertUpdate(PRODUCT_QUANTITIES,'insert',$iuExcludeArr,$uDatarr,$uCondition);
        echo $this->db->last_query();
        echo '</br>';
    }
    $totalSizesArr[] = $sizeId;
    $totalColorsArr[] = $colorId;
}
$totalSizesStr = implode(',', $totalSizesArr);
$totalColorsStr = implode(',', $totalColorsArr);
$this->product_model->quantityDelete(PRODUCT_QUANTITIES,$product_id,$totalColorsStr,$totalSizesStr);
```

I want to delete row with id 2 and 3. These 2 are not matching.

I know one solution is to delete all rows for product_id 18 and insert the new rows. But is there any other way without deleting all records and insert new rows?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)? plus i don't know exactly what you want. your `DELETE` query works fine: it doesn't match any of the 4 entries you got listed here, so it should not delete anything (because `color_id` is either 9 or 1 in your entries, so `NOT IN(9,1)` will always evaluate to false).

Comment: I want to delete row with id 2 and 3. These 2 are not matching.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you might want to look at your logic. Don't you mean to do:

```
DELETE FROM fc_product_quantities WHERE product_id=18 AND (color_id NOT IN (9,1) OR size_id NOT IN (23,24))
```

This is just a guess, because all the AND's might leave you with nothing to delete.

Comment: wow, you actually understood what he tried to do (before his additionals comments, updates). +1 for that :)

Comment: But unfortunately in another situation I have 4 rows with 1 unmatched row. In this case above query not working.

Comment: Analyse your needs first, then think about the logic. Can it be written in 1 query? If not, do you need two? When? But before everything else you need to analyse what it exactly is you want to do in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query exclude to much rows from delete.

```
DELETE
FROM fc_product_quantities
WHERE product_id=18
AND color_id NOT IN (9,1)
AND size_id NOT IN (23,24)
```

Example with a row like this :

```
Array
(
  [pid] => 18
  [color] => 9
  [size] => 50
)
```

This row will not be deleted because you exclude value 9 in `color_id`.
This will work :

```
DELETE
FROM fc_product_quantities
WHERE product_id = 18
AND (
    (color_id != 9 AND size_id != 23)
    OR
    (color_id != 1 AND size_id != 24)
)
```